# CSS to Make List Content Get Out of Flow

Tags: html, css

```css
.inside-article {background:gray}
```

```html
<div class="inside-article">
<p>Content 1</p>
<div class="entry-content" itemprop="text">
   <p>Content 2</p>
   <div class="is-layout-flow wp-block-query">
      <ul class="is-layout-flow wp-block-post-template">
        <li class="wp-block-post">Content List 1</li>
        <li class="wp-block-post">Content List 2</li>      
     </ul>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="meta-box">Content 3</div>
</div>
```

I need `li` tags to break out of flow so i can have them as new blocks that i can style as separate containers. Imagine rectangles separated by one another (independent), but aligned under one another automatically. The `li` blocks must NOT extend the containers above them. In the presentation above, they all follow the gray background, and i need the `li` tags to get cut out from the gray background, and be delimited boxes. Note that each container is dynamic in size.

I cant add more html to this structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.wp-block-post {margin:10px...}`
this is a separate item, alternatively change class name

or

&after ...

------editing

```css
.inside {
  background: #ccc;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  position:relative;
}
.in {
  margin-top: 10px ;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 8;
  

}
.in::before {
   content: attr(data-descr);
  height:50px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
margin-top:50px;
margin-left:150px;

  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class='inside'>
  <p>ABCD</p>
<div class='entry'>
  <ul>
<li class='in' data-descr="Abc"></li>
<li class='in' data-descr="Abc"></li>


</ul>
</div>
<div>ABCD2</div>
</div>
```

if you want each li to be separate, you should assign each li a separate class

if you can't edit html at all you can use js

Comment: it won't separate the li tags ... the margin will extend the gray background and thats not what i need. i need them to be independent from the '.entry-content'

Comment: use position absolute not resizing gray bg entry-content set position relative or add &after with position absolute and set li position relative, entry content set box-sizing:border-box

Comment: i've tried that as well, by giving postion relative to .entry-content and .meta-box, than postion absolute to li tags  and it wont work. doing it like this wont align the .meta-box under the li tags. they will overlap (the meta-box and li tags)

Comment: See if it's better now

Comment: i appreciate your input. unfortunately i can't use it as your css just adds a red box on top of each li. i have tried to adapt it to my css by replacing `before` element with the `li` class needed. I also remove sizes and top, left as i have dynamic content (which i've already mentioned before). in the end this would however bring me to my previous comment where i said i tried the same exact `position relative` and `position absolute` elements, the same way and they don't work..

Comment: adds a red field because it has background:red set, I don't have any red lines, maybe check this function in other browsers.